# numpy filling the diagonal 0 for 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I have a 3D array, how can I fill the diag of the first two dimensions to zero. For example

```
a = np.random.rand(2,2,3)
for i in range(3):
    np.fill_diagonal(a[:,:,i], 0)
```

Is there a way to replace the for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is one of the solution

```
a = np.random.rand(2,2,3)
np.einsum('iij->ij',a)[...] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The np.diag function returns a 2D diagonal matrix.

```
a[:,:,0] = np.diag((1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [6]: a = np.random.randint(1,10,(2,2,3))
   ...: for i in range(3):
   ...:     np.fill_diagonal(a[:,:,i], 0)
In [7]: a
Out[7]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [7, 4, 4]],

       [[8, 2, 7],
        [0, 0, 0]]])
```

Indexing a diagonal is easy - just use the same index array for both dimensions.  Thus the 0s we just set are:

```
In [8]: idx=np.arange(2)
In [9]: a[idx,idx,:]
Out[9]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

and used to set a value:

```
In [10]: a[idx,idx,:] = 10
In [11]: a
Out[11]: 
array([[[10, 10, 10],
        [ 7,  4,  4]],

       [[ 8,  2,  7],
        [10, 10, 10]]])
```